# "Next" button behaves like TAB on numeric soft keyboard. How to disable with jquery?

Tags: android, jquery, html, web-applications, android-softkeyboard

There is no GO button on the numeric keyboard. Not sure why… For `input type="tel"`, I'd like the NEXT button to just submit the form, so that I can attach functions to the `submit` event (smooth scrolling to the next form section). Instead it tabs straight to the next field (sometimes skipping sections).

I know I can attach functions to the `blur` event, but these fire after the tabbing takes place. So it ruins the smooth scroll.

`e.preventDefault` didn't stop the tabbing behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: _There is no GO button on the numeric keyboard_ --- Which keyboard are you testing against? [This is the default keyboard on Nexus 5](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Kqn0Qe2jO40/VDyJc_kKzKI/AAAAAAAAQHo/O2_PyDf3gbs/w485-h862-no/Screenshot_2014-10-14-11-07-50.png) with "GO" button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These are the two keyboards on Asus tablet, set to Android keyboard (not default Asus):
http://bit.ly/1z8kACm
http://bit.ly/1xPLBGc

input type="text" triggers the lettered keyboard. type="tel" triggers the numeric one. Hoping I can get the NEXT button to act like a GO button.